# how to delete a row that starts with the first character of the name?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table **Movie** which the movieID is the primary key and its foreign key is the movieID in the table Budget. The Movie table has an attribute MovieTitle that is the name of movie.

I want to know how I can delete the row that start with the first character "K" in the Movie table.

For example, i want to delete the movie title "Kingdom of Heaven", but I must delete the foreign key in the table Budge first. I want to know what is the command for this situation.

Comment: Can you precise what database you're using ? Are you using SQL as query language ?

Comment: You can use trigger or foreign key cascade delete.

Answer (score 4):

I think this would be your best option. You should have an `ON DELETE` foreign key constraint that would delete the corresponding record once deleted from your table.

```
DELETE FROM Movie WHERE SUBSTR(movieTitle, 1, 1) = 'K'
```

Answer (score 1):

Delete all records regarding to the movie with title "Kingdom of Heaven" and then you can also delete the movie too.

```
SELECT movieID FROM Movie WHERE movieTitle = 'Kingdom of Heaven'
```

this will return your movieID 
then delete from the second table records regarding to this id

```
DELETE * FROM (secondTable) WHERE movieID = (value got from the first query)
```

and now, finnaly you can delete the movie

```
DELETE * FROM Movie WHERE movieID = (value got from the first query)
```

Comment: i have to do this seperately or write them in 1 shot.

Comment: select new query by right click on the database ... and write in this order all the queries

Comment: This answer has nothing to do with the question.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use something like below in order to not face with dirty behavior in multi-user environment. The intention - to not permit change movie title during your delete statement.

```
declare 
 lMovieRec Movie%rowtype;
begin
 select *
 into lMovieRec
 from movie
 where SUBSTR(movieTitle, 1, 1) = 'K'
 for update nowait;

 delete from Budge  WHERE movieID = lMovieRec.id;

 delete from movie WHERE ID = lMovieRec.id; 
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

> For example, i want to delete the movie title "Kingdom of Heaven", but
>   I must delete the foreign key in the table Budge first. I want to know
>   what is the command for this situation.

You're probably better off by declaring the foreign key in Budge that references movies as `ON DELETE CASCADE`. When you do that, deleting a movie will automatically delete any rows in Budge that reference the table of movies.

To delete all the movies that start with "K" (an idea that I think is actually not likely to be what you really want), use something along these lines.

```
delete from movie
where MovieTitle like 'K%';
```

Specifying the entire title is *much* safer, but you should be aware that movies sometimes share titles. ("Speed", "The Fugitive", "Titanic", etc.)

```
delete from movie
where MovieTitle = 'Klute';
```

To make it crystal clear which of two movies you mean, when two movies share the same title, use either the MovieID alone, or use both the title and the id. (If the whole statement appears in log files, it's easier to see what's happened if you have *both* the title and the id number.)

```
delete from movie
where MovieTitle = 'Titanic'
  and MovieID = 42;
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
delete from Movie where MovieTitle like 'K%'
```

Comment: but dont we have to delete the foreign key movieID 1st, which is in the table budget?

Comment: And maybe he can also use `LIKE`, since your code won't work in any SQL dialect I know.

Comment: @JohnSaunders: Without quotation marks of some kind around K%, it won't work in any SQL dialect you don't know, either.